# What is a difference between ansible-playbook's switch/flag -v and -vvv?

Tags: ansible

What is a difference between ansible-playbook switch/flag -v and -vvv. The [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-v) just says -v, --verbose verbose mode (-vvv for more, -vvvv to enable connection debugging

what does more verbose exactly mean? is -vv going to be different than -vvv? I don't see -vv anywhere in documetnation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite common that debug messages have a verbosity level. Knowing how this is handled internally by ansible requires to dig inside ansible sources (which I didn't do in this specific case)

Meanwhile the [ansible `debug module`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html) follows this logic with the [`verbosity` parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html#parameter-verbosity)

So setting there `verbosity: 0` (default) will always show the debug, `verbosity: 1` only if you use at least `-v`, `verbosity: 2` only if you use at least `-vv`, etc.

The number of `v` determines the verbosity level. The more `v`s, the more details, depending on how the authors decided to implement the debugging details for each function/module/...